Power Bi Sharepoint folder connector is missing columns of new added csv file
In PowerBi I'm using a SharePoint folder connector to import few csv files. Now I added a new csv file which contains some additional columns which were not present on the previous files. The file gets detected and imported but the new columns are missing for some reason. Below is some sample code which represents the logic, but I had to change the paths and other sensitive names.
let
    // Load files from SharePoint
    Source = SharePoint.Files("https://samplesite.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite", [ApiVersion = 15]),

    // Filter rows to include only relevant files based on the folder path
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.StartsWith([Folder Path], "https://yourcompany.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/Shared Documents/yourfolder")),

    // Further filter to exclude hidden files
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),

    // Invoke custom function to transform files
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File", each #"Transform File"([Content])),

    // Rename columns if needed
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),

    // Keep only relevant columns
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File"}),

    // Dynamically expand all columns from the transformed files
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File"(#"Sample File"))),

    // Transform column types if needed
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1", List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Table Column1"), each {_, type text})),

    // Example of specific column type transformations (if needed)
    #"Changed Specific Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {
        {"Submit Date", type datetime},
        {"Start Date", type datetime},
        {"Stage Date", type any}
    })
in
    #"Changed Specific Types"

Did you discover the same problem in Power Bi and know a solution for it?
Thanks!

Post the contents of the custom function

Custom function Transform File (2):
= (Parameter2 as binary) => let
    Source = Csv.Document(Parameter2,[Delimiter=",", Columns=62, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
    #"Promoted Headers"

I see that the number of columns are hard coded here!

Take out columns=62,

Go into your function and take out the part that says
columns=62,

